# Safe acquisition of all striped lock at once

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Let's say I've implemented a striped lock to safely but efficiently access some data structure, but that structure has a method that requires all locks to be acquired at the same time. What is the most correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to acquire multiple locks at the same time, the only way to safely do that (i.e. avoid potential deadlock), is to always acquire the locks in the same order.  as long as you can come up with a consistent order for the locks and always acquire them in that order (and release them in the reverse order), it should work without deadlock.

Answer (score -1):

If you have implemented a striped lock to safely and efficiently access a data structure, but the data structure has a method that requires all locks to be acquired at the same time, you can modify your implementation to allow for this. Here are the steps you can follow:

1. First, create a new lock that will be used to synchronize the access to the data structure when all locks need to be acquired at the same time. You can use a simple `ReentrantLock` for this purpose.
2. Next, modify your striped lock implementation to acquire this new lock in addition to the striped locks when the method that requires all locks to be acquired is called. You can use the `tryLock()` method of the `ReentrantLock` to try to acquire the lock without blocking. If the lock cannot be acquired, you can release all the previously acquired striped locks and try again.
3. Once all the locks have been acquired, call the method on the data structure that requires all locks to be acquired.
4. Release all the locks in reverse order of acquisition, starting with the lock that was acquired last.

Here's an example of how the modified striped lock implementation might look like:

```
public class StripedLock {
private final int numStripes;
private final ReentrantLock[] locks;

// Constructor that creates the striped locks
public StripedLock(int numStripes) {
    this.numStripes = numStripes;
    this.locks = new ReentrantLock[numStripes];
    for (int i = 0; i < numStripes; i++) {
        this.locks[i] = new ReentrantLock();
    }
}

// Method to acquire all locks at once
public void acquireAllLocks() {
    List<ReentrantLock> acquiredLocks = new ArrayList<>();
    ReentrantLock allLocks = new ReentrantLock();

    // Acquire all striped locks
    for (int i = 0; i < numStripes; i++) {
        ReentrantLock lock = locks[i];
        if (lock.tryLock()) {
            acquiredLocks.add(lock);
        } else {
            // Release all previously acquired locks and try again
            for (ReentrantLock acquiredLock : acquiredLocks) {
                acquiredLock.unlock();
            }
            acquiredLocks.clear();
            i = -1; // start again from the first lock
        }
    }

    // Acquire the all-locks lock
    allLocks.lock();

    // Release all striped locks except the last one
    for (int i = acquiredLocks.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        acquiredLocks.get(i).unlock();
    }

    // Call the method that requires all locks to be acquired
    dataStructure.methodThatRequiresAllLocks();

    // Release all locks in reverse order of acquisition
    allLocks.unlock();
    for (int i = acquiredLocks.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        acquiredLocks.get(i).unlock();
    }
}
}
```

In this implementation, the `acquireAllLocks()` method tries to acquire all the striped locks first, and if successful, it acquires the all-locks lock and releases all the striped locks except the last one. Then, it calls the method that requires all locks to be acquired, and finally, it releases all the locks in reverse order of acquisition. If any of the striped locks cannot be acquired, it releases all the previously acquired locks and tries again from the first lock.

Comment: i'm not sure why you added the allLocks lock.  it doesn't actually do anything in your scenario (since you create it inside the method, no other thread can ever use the same lock).